# Custom Text Filed Input Format

Tags: ios

How to create a custom input format for  Text Filed. I am trying to allow user to enter values in the below format - A0B1234. So the Text Filed should allow entering values in that format only. Already I have tried by adding values to an array and compare the position, but it did not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UITextFieldDelegate, sample code -

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if range.location == 0{
            if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.letters) != nil{
                return true
            }
        }else if range.location == 1{
            if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil{
                return true
            }
        }else if range.location == 2{
            if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.letters) != nil{
                return true
            }
        }else{
            if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil{
                return true
            }
        }
        
        return false
}
```

Comment: Above answer was useful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression could be a best possible solution for this. Please check below links to know how to use regular expressions and more.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/108/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-swift and
"Validating Data" section in:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5765-regular-expressions-tutorial-getting-started